# Problem with configuration of hibernate batch insert

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jdbc

Hibernate batch insert is not working for me on Oracle.

I have read

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update

Having

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=30
hibernate.order_inserts=true
hibernate.order_updates=true
hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
```

there are still 2 separate inserts into the same table one by one (logged via net.ttddyy.dsproxy.support.ProxyDataSourceBuilder, not only bare hibernate).

What can be a problem? How can I diagnose it?

Can "type":"Prepared" be a problem ? (`"type":"Prepared", "batch":false,`)

```
2019-07-26 15:04:28.593 DEBUG 23724 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into STUDENT (version, ...) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-07-26 15:04:28.594  INFO 23724 --- [           main] n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener      : {"name":"Batch-Insert-Logger", "connection":4, "time":1, "success":true, "type":"Prepared", "batch":false, "querySize":1, "batchSize":0, "query":["insert into STUDENT (version, ...) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"], "params":[["0",...]}
2019-07-26 15:04:28.594 DEBUG 23724 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into STUDENT (version, ...) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-07-26 15:04:28.595  INFO 23724 --- [           main] n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener      : {"name":"Batch-Insert-Logger", "connection":4, "time":1, "success":true, "type":"Prepared", "batch":false, "querySize":1, "batchSize":0, "query":["insert into STUDENT (version, ...) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"], "params":[["0",...]]}
```